# How can I print a stock symbol that throws an error?

Tags: r

I'm trying to run the script below and it keeps failing.

```
###### rm(list=ls())

library(stockPortfolio) # Base package for retrieving returns
library(ggplot2) # Used to graph efficient frontier
library(reshape2) # Used to melt the data
library(quadprog) #Needed for solve.QP



# Create the portfolio using ETFs, incl. hypothetical non-efficient allocation
stocks <- c ("VCRA",
"AFFX",
"SGI",
"SAFM",
"SCAI",
"LINC",
"OGS",
"HIIQ",
"FLIR",
"MGEE",
"INTT",
"IPCI",
"DMRC",
"SBGL",
"UNTY",
"AEP",
"NAME",
"ED",
"WEC",
"MMYT",
"AWK",
"DRD",
"ISRG",
"CHUY",
"EDE",
"CHT",
"BGFV",
"VPCOU",
"NJR",
"FC",
"ROVI",
"SO",
"BXLT",
"NATH",
"VRNS",
"XEL",
"MBTF",
"MJCO",
"CMS",
"DLR",
"O",
"ADTN",
"SSS",
"SLP",
"PBY",
"NI",
"ORBC",
"CPB",
"OCLR",
"TLP",
"PROV",
"NWN",
"LNT",
"NTLS",
"PPC",
"NTT",
"WBMD",
"PLCE",
"NEE",
"EE",
"PMBC",
"PACB",
"AVA",
"IESC",
"HOFT",
"QSII",
"LPTH",
"INFY",
"DYAX",
"CPK",
"MMAC",
"CBNJ",
"IDSY",
"ONE",
"ITC",
"HLI",
"VHC",
"CTWS",
"SMBC",
"EQIX",
"LOCO",
"LEI",
"PNM",
"CYBE",
"PSA",
"YOKU",
"BDBD",
"ADMS",
"GMCR",
"DWA",
"LBMH",
"SCG",
"KMB",
"POR",
"ARG",
"ETR",
"WGL",
"CRAY",
"ES")



# Retrieve returns, from earliest start date possible (where all stocks have
# data) through most recent date
returns <- getReturns(stocks, freq="day", start = "2015-02-01", end = "2015-07-30") #Currently, drop index


#### Efficient Frontier function ####
eff.frontier <- function (returns, short="yes", max.allocation=NULL,
 risk.premium.up=2.95, risk.increment=.1){
 # return argument should be a m x n matrix with one column per security
 # short argument is whether short-selling is allowed; default is no (short
 # selling prohibited)max.allocation is the maximum % allowed for any one
 # security (reduces concentration) risk.premium.up is the upper limit of the
 # risk premium modeled (see for loop below) and risk.increment is the
 # increment (by) value used in the for loop


 covariance <- cov(returns)
 print(covariance)
 n <- ncol(covariance)


 # Create initial Amat and bvec assuming only equality constraint
 # (short-selling is allowed, no allocation constraints)
 Amat <- matrix (1, nrow=n)
 bvec <- 1
 meq <- 1


 # Then modify the Amat and bvec if short-selling is prohibited
 if(short=="no"){
 Amat <- cbind(1, diag(n))
 bvec <- c(bvec, rep(0, n))
 }


 # And modify Amat and bvec if a max allocation (concentration) is specified
 if(!is.null(max.allocation)){
 if(max.allocation > 1 | max.allocation <0){
 stop("max.allocation must be greater than 0 and less than 1")
 }
 if(max.allocation * n < 1){
 stop("Need to set max.allocation higher; not enough assets to add to 1")
 }
 Amat <- cbind(Amat, -diag(n))
 bvec <- c(bvec, rep(-max.allocation, n))
 }



 # Calculate the number of loops
 loops <- risk.premium.up / risk.increment + 1
 loop <- 1
 # Initialize a matrix to contain allocation and statistics
 # This is not necessary, but speeds up processing and uses less memory
 eff <- matrix(nrow=loops, ncol=n+3)
 # Now I need to give the matrix column names
 colnames(eff) <- c(colnames(returns), "Std.Dev", "Exp.Return", "sharpe")
 # Loop through the quadratic program solver
 for (i in seq(from=0, to=risk.premium.up, by=risk.increment)){
 dvec <- colMeans(returns) * i # This moves the solution along the EF
 sol <- solve.QP(covariance, dvec=dvec, Amat=Amat, bvec=bvec, meq=meq)
 eff[loop,"Std.Dev"] <- sqrt(sum(sol$solution*colSums((covariance*sol$solution))))
 eff[loop,"Exp.Return"] <- as.numeric(sol$solution %*% colMeans(returns))
 eff[loop,"sharpe"] <- eff[loop,"Exp.Return"] / eff[loop,"Std.Dev"]
 eff[loop,1:n] <- sol$solution
 loop <- loop+1
 }
 return(as.data.frame(eff))
}


# Run the eff.frontier function based on no short and 50% alloc. restrictions
eff <- eff.frontier(returns=returns$R, short="no", max.allocation=.50,
 risk.premium.up=2.95, risk.increment=.1)


# Find the optimal portfolio
eff.optimal.point <- eff[eff$sharpe==max(eff$sharpe),]


# graph efficient frontier
# Start with color scheme
ealred <- "#7D110C"
ealtan <- "#CDC4B6"
eallighttan <- "#F7F6F0"
ealdark <- "#423C30"

ggplot(eff, aes(x=Std.Dev, y=Exp.Return)) + geom_point(alpha=.1, color=ealdark) +
 geom_point(data=eff.optimal.point, aes(x=Std.Dev, y=Exp.Return, label=sharpe),
 color=ealred, size=5) +
 annotate(geom="text", x=eff.optimal.point$Std.Dev,
 y=eff.optimal.point$Exp.Return,
 label=paste("Risk: ",
 round(eff.optimal.point$Std.Dev*100, digits=3),"\nReturn: ",
 round(eff.optimal.point$Exp.Return*100, digits=4),"%\nSharpe: ",
 round(eff.optimal.point$sharpe*100, digits=2), "%", sep=""),
 hjust=0, vjust=1.2) +
 ggtitle("Efficient Frontier\nand Optimal Portfolio") +
 labs(x="Risk (standard deviation of portfolio)", y="Return") +
 theme(panel.background=element_rect(fill=eallighttan),
 text=element_text(color=ealdark),
 plot.title=element_text(size=24, color=ealred))
ggsave("Efficient Frontier.png")



transposed_object<-as.data.frame(t(eff.optimal.point))
colnames(transposed_object)<- c("stat")
subset(transposed_object, transposed_object $stat>0.05)
```

The problem is, one or more of these stocks don't have prices during the period I'm looking at, and this throws an error because no prices = no returns.  How can I modify the script to print any stock symbol with no prices, so I can just delete any/all from the list, and re-run the script and have it work the second time?

Thanks to all.

Comment: Can you post your example data and expected output? The vector of stock symbols does not help to answer your question.

Comment: I just edited my original post.  I thought all that was needed was the first part.  Everything is there now.  The concept comes from here.

http://economistatlarge.com/portfolio-theory/r-optimized-portfolio

Comment: While that is very good, I suggest you post a minimally reproducible set of data. It is impossible for any of us to run vast pieces of your code that rely on lot of packages and help you with it. You can create fake data and provide desired output from that fake data, explaining what logic you expect the intermediate steps to perform.

Comment: Also, don't put `rm(list=ls())` in code posted for other people to run.

Answer (score 0):

```
returns <- if( prices = returns) { getReturns(stocks, freq="day", start = "2015-02-01", end = "2015-07-30") } else (no prices = no returns) {add current date};
returns<- returns[-currentdate, ];
```

### then rerun your code. This is an outline of what I would do. Thoughts anyone?